# Как вывести текст setText на QDockWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qwidget

Делаю таким образом

```
    self.dockedWidget = QWidget(self)
    self.docked.setWidget(self.dockedWidget)
    self.dockedWidget.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
    textzz = QLabel.setText(self, 'bla bla')
    self.dockedWidget.layout().addWidget(textzz)
```

Но при компиляции выдаёт ошибку

> textzz = QLabel.setText(self, 'bla bla') TypeError: setText(self,
>   str): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QLabel'

Что я делаю не правильно? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QLabel` -- это класс, а `setText` нужно у объекта вызывать или сразу создать `QLabel` и в конструкторе положить текст:

```
self.dockedWidget = QWidget(self)
self.docked.setWidget(self.dockedWidget)
self.dockedWidget.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())

textzz = QLabel('bla bla')

# OR:
# textzz = QLabel()
# textzz.setText('bla bla')

self.dockedWidget.layout().addWidget(textzz)
```